# I cannot get my game charater to perform a "Double Jump"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to get my character to double jump in Unity with C#. This is the code I'm using but it won't let the character double jump. Anyone knows a solution to this problem?

```
public class Tito : MonoBehaviour {

public float speed = 1;  //SIDEWAYS SPEED
public float jump = 1;  //JUMP HEIGHT
public float width = 0.5079113f;  //CHARACTER WIDTH
public float score; //TOTAL AMOUNT OF COLLECTED COINS
public GUIText scoreText;
public bool inair = false; // TRUE = TITO IS IN AIR
public bool grounded = false; // TRUE = TITO IS ON THE GROUND
public bool doublejump = false; 

void Start () 
{
    GameObject Text = GameObject.Find("Text");
}


// COIN PICK UP //
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if(other.tag == "Coin")
    {
        Debug.Log ("Coins Collected = " + (score));
        (score) += 1;
        Destroy(other.gameObject);
    }
}

void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D coll) 
{

// DEATH HIT //
    if (coll.gameObject.tag == "Dead")
    {
        Debug.Log ("You died! Restarting Game"); 
        Application.LoadLevel (Application.loadedLevel);
    }

// CHECK TO SEE IF GROUNDED //
    if (coll.gameObject.name == "Ground")
    {
        Debug.Log ("Grounded");
        grounded = true;
        inair = false;
        doublejump = false;
    }

}

void Update () 
{

// LOCK ROTATION // 
    {
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(transform.rotation.eulerAngles.x, 0, 0);
    }


// INPUT - MOVEMENT //
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
    {
        gameObject.transform.Translate(speed, 0, 0);
        transform.localScale = new Vector3 (width, width, width);
    }

if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
    {
        gameObject.transform.Translate(-speed, 0, 0);
        transform.localScale = new Vector3 (-width, width, width);
    }



        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            if (grounded == true)
            {
                rigidbody2D.velocity = new Vector3 (0, jump, 0);
                Debug.Log ("SingleJump");
                grounded = false;
                doublejump = true;
            }
            else if (doublejump == true)
            {
                rigidbody2D.velocity = new Vector3 (0, jump, 0);
                Debug.Log ("DoubleJump");
                doublejump = false;             
            }
        }
    }

/*
if (grounded == true) // IF IN TOUCH WITH GROUND
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
        {
        rigidbody2D.velocity = new Vector3 (0, jump, 0);
            Debug.Log ("In-Air");
            inair = true;
            grounded = false;

        }
    }
*/
```

}

Comment: So what happens when you try?  What's written to the debug log?

Comment: I think you're not showing us everything. I cannot see an obvious mistake in this code. Can `Update()` be called while jumping? Are `singlejump` and `doublejump` declared in a method scope?

Comment: The Debug log says: "Grounded" when on the ground, and  "InAir" and "DoubleJump" when hitting space one time.

Comment: You seem to have changed your question to include the code from my answer (only call GetKey(KeyCode.Space) once). Does that mean that it worked? Please note that it is not best practice to change the question to include an answer, since the problem is then no longer present. The question and the answer do not make sense that way.

Comment: Oops sorry. Didn't notice that. It still doesn't work. Even with all the changes. I still have it as it is in the post above. Tried different things. No success. Thanks for letting me know

Comment: @Nils: see http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix it using a totally different way. It's easier, less code and works like charm.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Tito : MonoBehaviour {
    public float jumpspeed = 50;  //JUMP HEIGHT
    public bool grounded = false; // TRUE = TITO IS ON THE GROUND
    public int jumps = 0; // COUNTER TO CHECK THE AMOUNT OF JUMPS
    public int maxJumps = 2; // MAX EXTRA JUMPS

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D coll) {
        // CHECK TO SEE IF GROUNDED //
        if (coll.gameObject.name == "Ground") {
            Debug.Log ("Grounded");
            grounded = true;
            jumps = 0;
        }
    }

    void Update() {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && jumps < maxJumps) {
            Jump();
        }
    }

    void Jump() {
        rigidbody2D.velocity = new Vector3 (0, jumpspeed, 0);
        jumps = jumps +1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You first call to `Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space)` removed the space key from the input buffer.

You are reading the space key from the buffer, but are not using it in your method. You need to change it to:

```
void Update () 
{
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        if (grounded == true)
        {
            rigidbody2D.velocity = new Vector3 (0, jump, 0);
            Debug.Log ("SingleJump");
            grounded = false;
            doublejump = true;
        }
        else if (doublejump == true)
        {
            rigidbody2D.velocity = new Vector3 (0, jump, 0);
            Debug.Log ("DoubleJump");
            doublejump = false;             
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, those are different snippets from my code. The jump isn't in the OnCollisionEnter2d event there. Sorry. Will change now. Thanks for the quick reply tho :)

Comment: Still the same problem. When is Update being called?

Comment: @Nils it's a bit silly to change the question when an answer has been given already.

Comment: Yea I corrected the code. But it will singlejump. And the inair and doublejump stay false. Even after the singlejump. Only the Grounded will change from true to false when jumping. :(

Comment: It somehow looks like the two events are called at the same time because doublejump stays false all the time.

Comment: @Nils I'm guessing here, but do you release the space key between the single and double jump event? Perhaps you need to add code that waits until the space key is released before acting on a second space key event..

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to check when you are on the ground and when you are in the air.

```
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
{
    if(grounded)
    {
        rigidbody2D.velocity.y = 0;
        rigidbody2D.AddForce(new Vector2(0, jumpForce));
        canDoubleJump = true;
    } 

    else if(canDoubleJump)
    {
       canDoubleJump = false;
       rigidbody2D.velocity.y = 0;
       rigidbody2D.AddForce(new Vector2(0, jumpForce));
    }
}
```